# Получение значения поля структуры по указателю

Tags: c#

Как получить значение Odometer из структуры через параметр процедуры?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 2)]
public struct CoordinateItem
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public double Odometer;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public uint Time;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public ushort Angle;
}

private unsafe void SimpleCopy(CoordinateItem* ccdItem)
{
    var odometer =
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите весь необходимый код в виде текста.

Comment: `var odometer = (*ccdItem).Odometer;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Работает так? Оформлю ответом, если так. Забыл уже про этот топик

Comment: Да, вроде так))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь операцией разыменования указателя:

```
var odometer = (*ccdItem).Odometer;
```